# How I update WordPress theme and plugins

Tags: plugins, themes

I am using a premium theme and few plugins all are need to update. Previous when I update my theme I lose all of my customization. How can I update my theme and plugins so that plugin and theme customization unchanged.

Comment: Are you using a child theme?

Comment: No. I am not using that. Have any way to update without child theme?

Comment: A decently made theme/plugin will not lose customizations done through their option pages when updated. Only when you have modified the theme/plugin code you lose those adaptations.

Answer (score 1):

Did your customizations include changing the source code in the theme/plugin files? If yes, then you cannot update without loosing them. Instead you can use the [child theme](https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes) approach. Or you can make a plugin, that makes changes to another plugin or theme, which is harder than just changing the source files and you do not have full control, but then you can update without loosing the changes.

Comment: I didn't modify core file. I just setup slider, post, page, contact page and few others plugins. Actually I don't know how to use child theme. That means all of WordPress users are using child theme to update WordPress?

Comment: @WordpressStudent If you are talking about plugin and theme settings, they are usually stored in the database, so they should be still there after updating. You do not need a child theme for that. It is technically possible to store them in a file that is lost on update, but that would be crazy. If you are loosing settings talk to the theme author or support. It is not normal.